# What C++ libraries do Quora and Facebook use to access database?

Tags: c++, database, facebook, libraries

I've read that Quora and Facebook use C++ in the backend. Both of them process and fetch big amounts of data. What libraries do they use for that? Did they develop them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is known to have been written in php but now the php code is used to generate C++ code. To do that, t[hey developped a converter tool named HipHop](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/) that you can use yourself (Open source AFAIK).

I don't know about quora.

Amazon.com does use C++ but it's, AFAIK, their own code, not a library.

If you're interested in C++ web applications, you should try [CPPCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net).